# How can I create custom dynamic data mask function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, data-masking

In SQL Server 2016 or SQL Azure, there is a feature called [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking). However, it only has 4 types of masks. Is it possible to create custom mask functions? And how can I do this? I want a mask function like below(replace alphabet character with *):

String in database:

```
How do you do?
```

After masking:

```
*** ** *** **?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Custom String function

Something like this should do the trick

```
Alter Table[YourSchema].[YourTableName] Alter Column YourColumn Add masked with (function='Partial(0,"*",0)')
```

I didn't have time to test it so is a bit of a "blind clue"

You can check this article:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dynamic-data-masking-feature-in-sql-server-2016

I think it will be useful

Comment: This would create "*************" instead of "*** ** *** **"

Comment: @ChristopherElliott That's not right. This would actually return `*`. The mask value is static.